# Trying to enable Flink Entropy with S3, but entropy key is not generated

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to enable the entropy feature provided by Flink, but the at the end the `_entropy_` is not resolved (i mean there is no "key" generated)

I have the following configuration:

```
s3.access-key   my-key
s3.secret-key   ******

s3.entropy.key  _entropy_
s3.entropy.length   8

state.backend   filesystem
state.backend.incremental   true
state.backend.local-recovery    true

state.checkpoints.dir   s3p://<my-bucket>/_entropy_/flink/checkpoints/stage
state.checkpoints.num-retained  2
state.savepoints.dir    s3p://<my-bucket>/flink/savepoints/stage
```

when I open my-bucket I see the folder `_entropy_` instead of a random 8 characters folder.

For the declaration in the code :

```
env.enableCheckpointing(10000L, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)
   .getCheckpointConfig()     
   .enableExternalizedCheckpoints(ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.DELETE_ON_CANCELLATION);
env.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(3000L);
```

PS: I'm using Flink 1.11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a regression in Flink 1.11.2 that broke this feature; this was fixed in 1.11.4. See [FLINK-22081](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-22081) for details.